# How do I express this setter pattern in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

We usually do things lik

```
- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)foo
{
    _foo = foo;

// other computation

}
```

Getter and Setters give me warning that I cant set my own property. I am guessing it needs a computed property. What would be the best way to translate this idiom in Swift?

Comment: Can you give a less abstract example? Sometimes you'd use computed property. Sometimes you'd just use property observers. It depends upon what you're really trying to do. See the _Computed Properties_ and _Property Observers_ sections of [The Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_380). This question is unclear as to what precisely you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing computation tightly integrated with setting the internal storage of `foo`, especially if setting the storage is conditional on such computation, the computed-property/stored-property pair @matt suggests is probably the solution you need.

Otherwise—if you need to need to do work unconditionally in response to the setting of a property—what you're looking for is Swift's [property observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_380) feature.

```
var foo: Foo {
willSet(newFoo) {
    // do work that happens before the internal storage changes
    // use 'newFoo' to reference the value to be stored
}
didSet {
     // do work that happens after the internal storage changes
    // use 'oldValue' to reference the value from before the change
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "shadow" a public computed variable with a stored private variable, like this:

```
private var _foo : Foo!
var foo : Foo {
    get {
        return _foo
    }
    set (newfoo) {
        _foo = newfoo
    }
}
```

That is the analogy to what Objective-C `@synthesize` does. But you should also ask yourself whether you really need this. In most cases, you don't.